# stacked bar plot with fill of two count variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a stacked clustered bar graph with ggplot with Month on x-axis
two count variables (HAPI and Admissions) as fill.

Code to reproduce sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Group = c("Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post", 
            "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post"),
  Month = c("Jan", "Feb", "March", "Apr", "May", "June", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", 
            "Jan", "Feb", "March", "Apr", "May", "June", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept"),
  Unit = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200),
  HAPI = c(0, 1, 0, 6, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 6, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  Admissions = c(83, 77, 79, 114, 101, 20, 62, 96, 92, 64, 84, 74, 92, 130, 90, 15, 44, 82, 79, 83)
)
```

I want it to look something like this if possible.
[sample graph wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCJ7Q.jpg)

My main issue is that I can only get one fill (HAPI) when I want two and both are count and not categorical variables, so my graph doesn't look right. Any help would be appreciated!

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Month, y = Admissions, fill = HAPI)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  facet_grid(~ Group) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  labs(x='Month')
```

Comment: So the height of the bar should be Admissions + HAPI ?

Comment: @Julian_Hn The height of the bar should just be admissions. HAPI is just the people in admissions who developed an issue if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, we just overlay the plot with a second geom_bar for the HAPI cases and then do some manual overriding of the legend.
To keep the original order, we can use `fct_inorder` to make the bar go from Jan to Sept in Pre and Post.

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",mapping=aes(x=fct_inorder(Month),y=Admissions),fill="darkgrey",position="stack")  +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",mapping=aes(x=fct_inorder(Month),y=HAPI,fill="red"),position="stack") +
  facet_grid(~ fct_inorder(Group)) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red"),labels=c("HAPI")) + # Make the label appear as HAPI
  labs(x='Month',y="Admissions",fill="Type")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was able to modify your code a bit to get it to look like what I want, but the tip to use a second geom_bar instead of fill and fct_inorder really helped!